# Scale column using a condition

Tags: pandas

Lets say I have a dataframe, df, with columns "thing" and "value", but I want to make a new column "normalized" where value is divided by the mean average of values "of that thing"

so

| thing | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | t1 | 1 |
| a | t1 | 2 |
| a | t1 | 6 |
| b | t1 | 2 |
| b | t1 | 4 |
| b | t1 | 9 |
| a | t2 | 4 |
| a | t2 | 9 |
| a | t2 | 5 |

mean of 'a' thing, 't1' type is 3
mean of 'b' thing, 't1' type is 5
mean of 'a' thing, 't2' type is 6

should become:

| thing | type | value | norm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | t1 | 1 | 0.33... |
| a | t1 | 2 | 0.66... |
| a | t1 | 6 | 2.00 |
| b | t1 | 2 | 0.40 |
| b | t1 | 4 | 0.80 |
| b | t1 | 9 | 1.80 |
| a | t2 | 4 | 0.66.. |
| a | t2 | 9 | 1.50 |
| a | t2 | 5 | 0.83.. |

so a conditional version of:

df['norm'] = df['value']/df['value'].mean()

but grouping by thing and type to get the relevant mean value.
I am not sure if this needs some kind of conditional groupby or some kind of apply function processing by row, but I think to use pandas properly you really want to make use of a vectorized calculation on the column.

Comment: Also please look at how to produce a minimal reproducible example or your questions won't get much traction. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for Series with same size like original column, so possible division:

```
df['norm'] = df['value']/df.groupby(['thing', 'type'])['value'].transform('mean')
print (df)
  thing type  value      norm
0     a   t1      1  0.333333
1     a   t1      2  0.666667
2     a   t1      6  2.000000
3     b   t1      2  0.400000
4     b   t1      4  0.800000
5     b   t1      9  1.800000
6     a   t2      4  0.666667
7     a   t2      9  1.500000
8     a   t2      5  0.833333
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.groupby(['thing', 'type'])['value'].transform('mean'))
0    3
1    3
2    3
3    5
4    5
5    5
6    6
7    6
8    6
Name: value, dtype: int64
```